# Renombrar atributo por medio de xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Tengo este xml

```
<listado>
<usuario estado="activo">
<apellido>Gonzalez</apellido>
<nombre>Fuz</nombre>
<fechaRegistro>12/10/2020</fechaRegistro>
<username>fuz1655</username>
<fechaBaja></fechaBaja>
</usuario>
</listado>
```

He conseguido que a los elementos por ejemplo nombre se cambie a name con este codigo:

```
<xsl:template match="nombre">
  <name>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </name>
</xsl:template>
```

La salida es algo así:
Gonzalez
Fuz
12/10/2020
fuz1655

Necesito cambiar el estado de usurio que salga en la transformacion y que en ve de poner estado ponga status

Creo que se podria hacer con este codigo pero no lo entiendo muy bien:

```
<xsl:template match="@lastname">
<xsl:attribute name="surname">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

he ido probando pero no me ha funcionado?

Comment: UP!!! haber si alguien puede ayudarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para transformar el atributo `estado` a `status` puedes utilizar

```
<xsl:template match="@estado">
  <xsl:attribute name="status" select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

con XSLT 2 o 3 o

```
<xsl:template match="@estado">
  <xsl:attribute name="status">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

con XSLT 1.

Para que funcione y para que se transforme los atributos también tienes que utilizar `<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>` en cualquier `xsl:template` para elementos como `usuario` o `*` en general.

Comment: Al final lo consegui hace tiempo, te voy a dar la mejor respuesta porque creo que algo asi hize al final ty